# Updated HTML form not recognized by Rails submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a simple form that I am dynamically changing elements of.  When I submit this form via a submit_tag it does not pass along the changed elements to the server.  What do I need to add?  Somewhat new to Rails so any help would be appreciated.

form:

```
<form action="/cabinets" id="cabinets_form" method="post">
  <div id="main_body">
    <%= render 'layouts/body_header' %>
  </div>
</form>
```

body header:

```
<div style="width: 1250px; position: relative; left: -150px; height: 50px;">
  <%= text_field_tag 'nbr', nil, :style => 'width: 30px; font-family: monospace; position: relative; left: 60px;', maxlength: 3 %>
</div>
```

jQuery to change text_field in main_body

```
$('#nbr').attr('id', 'nbr_0');
```

The id is changed correctly and is seen when viewing the html but when I submit the form, the information sent over is: ":nbr => ''" instead of ":nbr_0 => ''". Using rails 3.2.13.

Edit:

Here is the body header with the hidden element:

```
<div style="width: 1250px; position: relative; left: -150px; height: 50px;">
  <%= text_field_tag 'nbr', nil, :style => 'width: 30px; font-family: monospace; position: relative; left: 60px;', maxlength: 3 %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "hidden_info", nil %>
</div>
```

Trying to update the value after I change the name with this code.

```
$('#hidden_info').attr('name', 'hidden_info_0');
$('#hidden_info').html("test");
```

The output for the params is: "hidden_info_0"=>"".  I would like it to be "hidden_info_0"=>"test".

Comment: I have this working now but my hidden elements values are not coming through?  Pretty much the same setup except they have the hidden_field_tag inside the body header div.  The appropriate names are ok server side, "hidden_name_0", but the values are not coming along with them.

Comment: can you show the code for  the hidden fields

Comment: I find the railspanel extension on chrome really useful for debugging what values are assigned and which are not.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was setting the .html() and not the .val().  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also change the `name=`. The point of fields having both `name=` and `id=` is the latter can be unique to a `<form>` even if it's repeated across a page of many forms. An `id=` must be unique to a page.

```
$('#nbr').attr('name', 'nbr_0');
```

You must decide if you also want to change the `id`...

Comment: Thank you! Almost all working now. Please see comment in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not working because `id` is an html/css layout element, but the form control is actually `name` -- so instead of changing `id` instead you'll call:

```
$('#nbr').attr('name', 'nbr_0');
```

Comment: Thank you! Almost all working now. Please see comment in my question.